# css not following displayed rules

Tags: css, developer-tools

According to Chrome, the border width rule is 4px, but it is displaying a width of 0 anyway (as you can see from the screenshot). Firefox is showing the same thing. I've tried a million ways to get the borders to show up (I'm inside a media query for mobile) but it just won't do it.

[image: my style is being overridden]

Under what conditions will a browser override the rules it shows as applying? Usually this tool points me directly to where the problem is, but in this case the tool appears to indicate I'm doing everything right.

Comment: Dumb question: are you sure there isn't a rule taking priority over that one?

Comment: Check if there's another rule applying and think in use `mobile-first`. Put the code you want for mobile as default, and use media queries for bigger resolutions.

Comment: That looks like **minus 4px**. Are you sure you don't have typo somewhere?

Comment: This screenshot was from Chrome's developer tools- Computed tab. This is where you go to find priority issues.  Every other time it tells me which line number of the css file is taking priority over what I expect.  In this case the priority is for a 4px top border width, but it's just not displaying it. Hence my frustration.

What we are viewing is NOT the css, but the way chrome interprets the css file.  It is not -4px.

I know there is a mistake somewhere. Safari and firefox show the same thing.  If I knew how I tricked all three rendering engines, I may be able to get a lead on how to fix.

Comment: what I usually do in these cases is removing or commenting components so I can isolate the problem. In that way you could create a jsfiddle or likely to provide a working example of the behaviour anybody can see

Comment: Please post your code